# Need to transpose multiple excel rows to columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

I am having following data in an excel sheet:

[image]

Now i need to transpose the data in such a way that i get the following result:
[image]

I am having a very huge data set like this in excel(thousands of dealer numbers). So manually transposing each and every dealer is not possible.

Can anyone help me out here?

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Chris, is it really a duplicate? They're not asking for a vba code. anyway,  @Vaishak, you can simply pivot it, and copy the transposed table for further transformations if it's a one-off analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the transpose function, passing it the range that you are wanting to transpose and press Crtl +Shift + Enter then you should get the result that you are looking for.  If the result is to small you can drag and change the result area, press Crtl + Shift + Enter again and the formula should recalculate your transpose.

`=TRANSPOSE(A1:C2)` will look like `{=TRANSPOSE(A1:C2)}` in the formula bar once Crtl +Shift + Enter have been pressed and the function has executed.

[Microsoft Documentation for Transpose function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRANSPOSE-function-ed039415-ed8a-4a81-93e9-4b6dfac76027)

[screen shot of simple result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWOdm.png)